# No <servlet> or <servlet-mapping> in my web.xml

Tags: java, xml

Here is my web.xml file.
In this I have no `<servlet>` nor `<servlet-mapping>` block.

So can we write it by ourself if it is not there?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>letscode</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Can we write servlet and servlet mapping block by our own??

Comment: Yes you are supposed to, if it not present.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse will handle servlet mappings for you by default. If you want, you can check it in the project explorer. It is under the section Deployment descriptors->Servlet Mappings. Make sure the servlet mappings are correct over there, that'll be enough!